# How do I cite websites in vancouver style using bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I have seen some people suggest

```
note = {\url{http://example.com/}}
howpublished= {\url{http://example.com/}}
```

This works to a point but I need to explicitly say stuff like "[online]" and I cannot use `note` or `howpublished` more than once. The result is I cannot write complete references for my websites. This is the format I expected to use:

> Author/Editor (use the corporate author if no individual author or editor is named)
>
> Title (this should be in italics)
>
> [Online]
>
> Available from: URL
>   [Date of access]

This is how it is meant to look:

> European Space Agency. *ESA: Missions, Earth Observation: ENVISAT.* [Online]. Available from: http://envisat.esa.int/ [Accessed 3rd July 2008].

The relevent packages I am using are:

```
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{url}
```

bibliography style:

```
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
```

Comment: Which bibliography style do you use?

Comment: added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't mention which entry type you're employing, so I'll assume it's the `@misc` entry type. If this assumption is correct, the following structure  might work for you:

```
@misc{esa,
   author  = "{European Space Agency}",
   title   = "\emph{{ESA: Missions, Earth Observation: ENVISAT}}",
   howpublished = "[Online]. Available from: \url{http://envisat.esa.int/}",
   note    = "[Accessed 3rd July 2008]"
}
```

[image]

Some details to note:

- the use of curly braces in the `author` field to denote the fact that it's a "corporate" author rather than a person with first name "European", middle name "Space", and surname "Agency",
- the use of the `\emph{}` command inside the `title` field, which is required because the `unsrt` bibliography style does *not* by default italicize the contents of the title field of entries of type `@misc`, and
- the use of curly braces in the `title` field to prevent BibTeX from rendering the words ESA and ENVISAT in (mostly) lowercase letters.

Comment: I ended up working around it slightly differently but either would have done. I did it like this:     @misc{esa,
   author  = "{European Space Agency}",
   title   = "\emph{{ESA: Missions, Earth Observation: ENVISAT}{[Online]}}",
   howpublished = " Available from: \url{http://envisat.esa.int/}",
   note    = "[Accessed: 3rd July 2008]"
}